# android java is not enclosing class

Tags: java, android

this is my class

```
 public class mm {

 public  class MessageHandler {
    public HashMap<String, Command> commandMap;

    public MessageHandler() {
        this.commandMap = new HashMap<>();
        commandMap.put("init", new CreateOfferCommand());
        commandMap.put("offer", new CreateAnswerCommand());
        commandMap.put("answer", new SetRemoteSDPCommand());
        commandMap.put("candidate", new AddIceCandidateCommand());
    }

    public Emitter.Listener onMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
            try {
                String from = data.getString("from");
                String type = data.getString("type");
                JSONObject payload = null;
                if(!type.equals("init")) {
                    payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");
                }
                // if peer is unknown, try to add him
                if(!peers.containsKey(from)) {
                    // if MAX_PEER is reach, ignore the call
                    int endPoint = findEndPoint();
                    if(endPoint != MAX_PEER) {
                        Peer peer = addPeer(from, endPoint);
                        peer.pc.addStream(localMS);
                        commandMap.get(type).execute(from, payload);
                    }
                } else {
                    commandMap.get(type).execute(from, payload);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    public Emitter.Listener onId = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            String id = (String) args[0];
            mListener.onCallReady(id);
        }
    };


    public Emitter.Listener onCall = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            String id = (String) args[0];
            mListener.onCalling(id);
        }
    };
}
 ......................
 .........
}
```

and when i call the inner class from another class its give me an enclosing class

```
 mm.MessageHandler messageHandler = new mm.MessageHandler();
```

when i make inner class messageHandler  a static the error gone but its shown anothe error inside inner class so can i call the inner class without make it static ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mm n = new mm(); 
mm.MessageHandler messageHandler = n.new MessageHandler();
```

or use static in your inner class

hope that's help